# PHP Mysql to PDF

Tags: php, pdf, text

I'm trying to make PDF from mysql, php.
When make pdf then text generate in one line.
How to wrap text ? I want to show multi line in one column like wrap text. My code is below

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
        //$prdid = $res[0];
        $empid = $res[1];
        $specification = $res[2];
        $prn = $res[3];
            $qty = $res[4];
            $esp = $res[5];
           // $pdf->Cell(25,7,$prdid);
        $pdf->Cell(25,7,$empid);
            $pdf->MultiCell(30,7,$specification);
            $pdf->Cell(40,7,$prn);
            $pdf->Cell(30,7,$qty);
            $pdf->Cell(30,7,$esp);
            $pdf->Ln(); 
        }
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Please help me

[I want to se as below picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huqlt.jpg)

Comment: Have you an output ? if yes please add here

Answer (score 0):

You have to use additional parameters to your Cell() function. To break the sentences in new line you have to use it as:

```
$pdf->Cell(25,7,$empid,0,1);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,7,$specification,0,1);
        $pdf->Cell(40,7,$prn,0,1);
        $pdf->Cell(30,7,$qty,0,1);
        $pdf->Cell(30,7,$esp,0,1);
```

'0' represents no border, and '1' represents newline. You should refer the fpdf website for looking it up. Here's the reference I used: 
http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm